# Get Video Width and Height from Azure Media Player

Tags: javascript, html5-video, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I have video's I'm streaming from Azure Media Services and are being rendered in my web page using Azure Media Player [API](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/).

I don't know ahead of time what the videos dimensions are (and they will vary). My issue is that when I play the video there is a black border (either at top/bottom or at left/right) around the video if I don't create the video element with the correct ratio to match the video. See for example the image below, notice the large black borders on the left and right of the video. I'd like to get the video size so I can correct the dimensions and get rid of the border.

[image]

The Azure Media Player API seems to say I can get the [videoWidth](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html#amp.player.videowidth) and [videoHeight](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html#amp.player.videoheight). But I'm not sure (in Javascript) what object to get those values from.

In my script below, when I `console.log` the `player` object I don't see `videoWidth` or `videoHeight` as part of the player object.

```
let myOptions = {
    controls: true,
    autoplay: true,
    logo: { enabled: false }
};
myPlayer = amp(video, myOptions, () => {
    console.log(myPlayer);
});
myPlayer.src([{
    src: "<manifestURL>",
    type: "<type>"
}]);
```

The following screenshot is what gets logged. Unless I'm missing something, I don't see the `videoWidth` or `videoHeight` values.

[image]

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have not tested so I leave it as a comment, videoWidth/videoHeight are functions, also you should use the `this` keyword inside the ready handler, eg. `amp(video, options, () => console.log(this.videoWidth())`.

Comment: thanks, you're correct that videoWidth is a function, I don't know what I was thinking... however when I used `this` it doesn't work. Using `myPlayer.videoWidth()` worked for me. If you post as the answer i'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually videoWidth/videoHeight are functions.

Also you should use the `this` keyword inside the ready handler.

For example :

```
amp(video, options, () => console.log(this.videoWidth())
```